# Safari is everywhere BUG, Html5 "dataset" attribute can not be obtained

Tags: javascript, html, dataset

Html5 "dataset" attribute can not be obtained. My Safari version 10.1.2 (12603.3.8)

"dataset.hasOwnProperty" can not determine whether the property exists. Please use the Safari browser test.

```js
var a= document.getElementById("a");
var b= document.getElementById("b");
var c= document.getElementById("c");
console.log(a.dataset.hasOwnProperty("defaultValue"));
c.value = b.dataset.hasOwnProperty("defaultValue");
console.log(c.value);
```

```html
<input id="a" value="a"/>
<input id="b" value="b" data-default-value="B"/>
<input id="c" value="c"/>
```

```js
var a= document.getElementById("a");
var b= document.getElementById("b");
var c= document.getElementById("c");
//a.dataset.hasOwnProperty("defaultValue"); //Has been annotated
c.value = b.dataset.hasOwnProperty("defaultValue");
console.log(c.value);
```

```html
<input id="a" value="a"/>
<input id="b" value="b" data-default-value="B"/>
<input id="c" value="c"/>
```

Comment: can you explain your problem little bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your issue is that `hasOwnProperty` doesn't return `true` for the `b` element on Safari (it doesn't on iOS Chrome, and *does* on desktop Chrome), well, that's not defined behavior, so don't rely on it.

Instead, you can check for `undefined`, since you will only get `undefined` if the property isn't set (all properties that are set will return strings, because `dataset` is a [`DOMStringMap`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#domstringmap)):

```js
var a= document.getElementById("a");
var b= document.getElementById("b");
var c= document.getElementById("c");
console.log(a.dataset.defaultValue !== undefined);
c.value = b.dataset.defaultValue !== undefined;
console.log(c.value);
```

```html
<input id="a" value="a"/>
<input id="b" value="b" data-default-value="B"/>
<input id="c" value="c"/>
```

Comment: Well, I will use your method to judge. hasOwnProperty is not stable and should not be used. Thank you.